# Want to apply set prices based on quantity in cart (tier prices for multiple products)

Tags: price

I sell umbrellas (different colors) and am setting up my Magento cart. I would like the pricing to be set to be:

> 1 umbrella = 15.95
>   2 for $25, 3 for $34.

Additional quantities above 3 would be each at the the individual price for the 3 quantity amount (11.34 each).

(I currently have each umbrella with a price of $15.95.) What kind of promotion rule in the cart would accomplish this?

Creating Tier pricing, as suggested, will not work, as I have numerous color umbrellas, each set up as separate products with a price of $15.95. Tier pricing on each color umbrella would give the discount only if, say, 3 GREEN umbrellas are purchased, but NOT if 2 GREEN and 1 BLUE are ordered.

I need the discount applied to the TOTAL Quantity in the cart using the following: 1 umbrella - 15.95, 2 umbrellas - $25, 3 umbrellas - $34, 4 or more umbrellas adds $11.34 for each additional umbrella.  Can this be done?

And, can it be done within the admin panel without the use of a plug-in?

I have tried, pretty successfully, with setting this up with three rules similar to what you now suggest. However, can you explain what the fixed discounts of 4,61 and 3,45 mean?

Comment: Please check my updated answer using shopping cart price rules. It should work for your updated question.

Comment: (15.95 - 3.45) * 2 = 25 and (15.95 - 4.61) * 3 = 34.42

Comment: Hi Larry, can you please accept my answer if this solves your question?

Answer (score 4):

To do this you can add tier prices for the product.

Go to the product page in the Magento admin area and navigate to the 'Price' tab. There you will have an attribute called 'Tier Price' where you can configure the price per ordered quantity.

[image]

**Edit: As per request a solution with shopping cart price rules:**

You can do this by making 2 separate rules.

**Rule number 1:**

Conditions:

[image]

Actions:

[image]

**Rule number 2:**

Conditions:

[image]

Actions:

[image]

Now make sure that rule 2 is executed **before** rule number 1 by giving it a lower priority and you're done :-) Rule number 1 won't be executed because rule number 2 has 'stop further rules processing' enabled.

You can of course change the conditions to match an attribute like partial SKU or attribute_set instead of a category. This is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Normally I wouldn't post a plugin, but I recently had luck with this one from WebShopApps - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tiered-pricing-across-multiple-products.html

The plugin will not work with grouped or bundled products (unless you modify it).

I do not work for WebShopApps.