# Calculate total price of cart depending on quantity

Tags: category, cart

I am trying to setup 3 different tier prices (all of which are in the same category):

- 0-5 products - £2.50
- 6-10 products - £5
- 11-20 products - £10

Note: Creating Tier pricing will not work, as I have numerous colors of these products. For example: Let's say I order 4 products from:

- Product A (blue)
- Product B (green)
- Product C (black)

...Equalling 12 products.

The cart would need to adhere to the consumer purchasing '11-20 products', not '0-5 products' for each item. Therefore category tier pricing would not work in this instance.

Essentially, I am trying to create something like this:
[Want to apply set prices based on quantity in cart (tier prices for multiple products)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69260/want-to-apply-set-prices-based-on-quantity-in-cart-tier-prices-for-multiple-pro)

However, it's going to be a little trickier to implement when I have ranges in the tier pricing.

**Edit: Partly found the solution. I have had to set up 20 individual rules which sets up a specific discount for the amount of products in the basket, view below:**

https://gyazo.com/f8f6e5b033836aeb82abb5d2477766f8 - Rule fires when 15 products are in the basket from a particular category
https://gyazo.com/3367fb8df96b64ee5c639fc943723aa8 - Applies 2.50 discount, but only to 11 products (£2.50 * £4 = £10).

However, the problem is that this ONLY works for 1 product. If I add, say, 6 green products and 9 red products (15 overall, which should charge £10), the discount does do not work because the `Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To` field only works for a specific product.

Any workarounds for this? I feel like the only way to fix this would be a Magento plugin. If there are any free ones around which will help for this, please let me know!